# MySQL: check max chracter length (ERROR 1118 (42000): Row size too large)

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm trying to convert/copy MyISAM to InnoDB table and I'm getting the following error message:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO test.innodb_table
    SELECT * FROM test.myisam_table
ERROR 1118 (42000): Row size too large (> 8126).
Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
    or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help.
In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.
```

The MyISAM table has many `VARCHAR(255)` columns so it looks like it's reaching the maximum row size limit for InnoDB table.

Questions:

1. How can I check on which row(s) the query above is actually failing so I can potentially remove it? I tried to use where clause and I was able to insert ~5000 rows this way but the orignal table has over 2 million rows.
2. I would like to limit the size of these variable length columns. How I can check the max character length for all columns? Pseudocode: `if column type equal to VARCH (255), show rows with max character length`

**UPDATE: Thu Apr 16 15:58:19 BST 2015:**

I constructed the following query to get a list of rows that exceed the max row length:

```
mysql> SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 102400;
    SELECT CONCAT('SELECT id, ',
             GROUP_CONCAT('LENGTH(', 'IFNULL(', COLUMN_NAME, ',
                      0)', ')' SEPARATOR '+'), ' AS total_length
        FROM myisam_table HAVING total_length > 8126;') AS 'Query'
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = (SELECT DATABASE())
      AND TABLE_NAME = 'myisam_table'\G
```

When I execute a query from the output of the query above, I receive a list of rows with a size greater than 8126 bytes:

```
+---------+--------------+
| id      | total_length |
+---------+--------------+
|     489 |        10938 |
|    5244 |         9141 |
|    5869 |         9680 |
|    6083 |        21284 |
|    6654 |         8644 |
...
```

I can then successfully insert this query so I don't understand how this exactly works and where is this size limit imposed:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO test.innodb_table SELECT * FROM test.myisam_table WHERE id = 489;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html), your problem is not with `VARCHAR` fields. However:

1. `SELECT id, LENGTH(field1)+LENGTH(field2)...+LENGTH(field_n) AS total_length WHERE total_length > 8126`
2. Can be done using 2 queries for each field. (This can be done in a complex query if you want to use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`):

   - `SELECT MAX(LENGTH(field1)) INTO @max_length1 FROM table_name`;
   - `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE LENGTH(field1)=@max_length1;`

**Note:** Increasing `innodb_page_size`'s value may be helpful in your case.

### Edit

To generate all the queries with the help of `information_schema`, run the following queries:

```
CREATE TABLE queries(field_name varchar(255), query1 varchar(4000), query2 varchar(4000));

INSERT INTO queries SELECT column_name, 
CONCAT('SELECT MAX(LENGTH(',column_name,')) INTO @max_length FROM table_name;'), 
CONCAT('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE LENGTH(',column_name,')=@max_length;')
FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema='test' and table_name='myisam_table';

SELECT * FROM queries;
```

Note that you have to run query1 then query2 from the result. DO NOT run all query1 then all query2!

Comment: `Ref. 1` this table has many columns, is there a way to pull column names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` in order to sum their length?

Comment: `Ref. 2` could you please give me some hints how to construct this query using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`

Comment: I added that to the answer. However, it is not recommended to have huge number of VARCHAR fields in one table.